# Can't Hit a WCF webservice which is being published by Visual Studio

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, iis

**UPDATE:** I don't know if this helps anyone diagnose this issue but the wsdl has the end point as:

```
http://localhost:8523/Temp/WebService.svc/WebService.svc
```

Which is wrong, I've tried manually changing the endpoint to remove the extra bit at the end and it still returns a 404

**/Update**

I'm working on a web service using WCF, when I run the VS2010 debugger I get the following error message:

> The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly.

The solutions to this I've found online say that I should add [ServiceContract] to the interface but it's already there.

I've also seen people say that I have to delete the  tag from the csproj file but doing this makes the project a class library rather than a web service.

But my browser opens to a directory listing and I can navigate to the wsdl generated by the container by clicking on the .svc file and then clicking on the link to .svc?wsdl

If I try and hit the service from an application or from the WCF Service Tester I get an exception with a 404, I cbbled together a test app and here is the exception it gives me:

```
Sending Message: Make Call: InteractionId [rt], Destination [ert], ExternalReferenceId [ert], userIdentifier [ert] attachedData [rt]
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8523/WebService.svc?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Sabio.Avaya.AACC.ProxyServiceLibary.IProxyService.MakeCall(MakeCallRequestData MakeCallRequestData)
   at Sabio.Avaya.AACC.ProxyServiceLibary.WSPipeProxyClient.MakeCall(MakeCallRequestData MakeCallRequestData) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebService\RemoteClientLib\WSPipeProxyClient.cs:line 42
   at ClientLibTestUI.WcfTestApp.MPCWSButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebService\ClientLibTestUI\Form1.cs:line 97
```

Here is my Web.config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="WebService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="DefaultWSBinding"
                  name="WSEndPoint"
                  contract="IWebService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Temp/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultNetTcpBindingConfig"
                 maxConnections="5"
                 portSharingEnabled="true" >
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>

      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultWSBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

      <mexHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </mexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServerServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>

        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong? I get a similar problem if I host in IIS or the built in webserver in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

The service tag in your config is wrong. Should have been something as below:

```
<service name="namespace.WebService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="WebService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="DefaultWSBinding"
                  name="WSEndPoint"
                  contract="namespace.IWebService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Temp/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

The name value in the service element and the contract value in the endpoint element should be fully qualified.

Comment: That is the result of me sanitising my Web.config to remove references to clients, the service name and endpoint contract both have namespaces. Sorry.

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS? Do you have a .svc file in your project. Do you mean the service name and endpoint contract in the config are specified as fully qualified names

Comment: I've tried hosting in IIS and in Cassini (Visual Studio) I have a .svc file which implements a [ServiceContract] I'm going to try reloading the code in a clean solution and see if that works...

Comment: Are you able to browse to the service page and view the wsdl in IE? Also try to invoke the web service using Fiddler and monitor the request response and see how it goes?

Comment: I can browse to the wsdl using Service_Name.svc?wsdl and I've loaded that it into SOAP UI which will generate stubs for the service but it just 404's when I try to execute any methods.

Comment: Is the WCF Service on the same machine? From the wsdl you should be able to know the SOAP address and that should be the URL your web service is on. Also can you set the address property value to empty string in the endpoint element and see if that works

Comment: It's on the same machine, I copied the code over to a new project and it's working fine. I have no idea what was wrong with it...

Comment: Try stripping out one by one in your actual project to narrow down what is causing the problem.